# Android application not shown when home button is clicked [Recents]

Tags: android, android-activity

I have noticed a strange behavior for my app. Whenever I press the home button my app gets killed. I don't see the application in application stack. I can see other application which were launched earlier. Initially I doubted about the `android:launchMode="singleInstance"` so I changed it to `android:launchMode="singleTop"` but this still doesn't work. 
 Here is my manifest file entires.

```
  <manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
          xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
          package="com.my.finder.android.core"
          android:installLocation="auto">



   <application
         android:name=".AndroidApplication"
         android:allowBackup="false"
         tools:replace="android:allowBackup"
         android:icon="@mipmap/icon"
         android:label="@string/app_name"
         android:largeHeap="true"
         android:theme="@style/Theme.MYTheme">


      <activity
            android:name=".Popup"
            android:permission="com.my.permission.INTERNAL_ACTIVITES"
            android:process=":Popup"/>

      <activity
            android:name=".SignInActivity"
            android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden|screenSize"
            android:excludeFromRecents="true"
            android:launchMode="singleTask"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait"
            android:taskAffinity=":extratask"
            android:theme="@style/Theme.NoTitle">
         <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN"/>

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER"/>
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT"/>
         </intent-filter>
         <!-- intent-filter for Optimizely -->
         <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW"/>

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT"/>
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE"/>

            <data android:scheme="@string/optimizely_scheme"/>
         </intent-filter>
         <!-- this is the click_action of the push message (once kiln will support it, AFMI-13756) -->
         <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="OPEN_MAP_ACTIVITY" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
         </intent-filter>
      </activity>

      <activity
            android:name=".FinderMapActivity"
            android:launchMode="singleTop"
            android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden|screenSize"
            android:exported="true"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait"
            android:permission="com.my.permission.INTERNAL_ACTIVITES"
            android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan">
      </activity>
      <activity
            android:name=".LandingScreenActivity"
            android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|screenSize"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait"
            android:permission="com.my.permission.INTERNAL_ACTIVITES"
            android:theme="@style/Theme.NoTitle">
      </activity>
      <activity
            android:name=".fragment.SurveyFragmentActivity"
            android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|screenSize"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait"
            android:permission="com.my.permission.INTERNAL_ACTIVITES"
            android:theme="@style/Theme.NoTitle">
      </activity>
      <activity
            android:name=".SignupWelcomeActivity"
            android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden|screenSize"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait"
            android:permission="com.my.permission.INTERNAL_ACTIVITES"
            android:theme="@style/Theme.NoTitle"
            android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize">
      </activity>
      <activity
            android:name=".CreateAccountActivity"
            android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden|screenSize"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait"
            android:permission="com.my.permission.INTERNAL_ACTIVITES"
            android:theme="@style/Theme.NoTitle"
            android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize">
      </activity>
      <activity
            android:name=".AddAssetsActivity"
            android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden|screenSize"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait"
            android:permission="com.my.permission.INTERNAL_ACTIVITES"
            android:theme="@style/Theme.NoTitle"
            android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize|stateHidden">
      </activity>
      <activity
            android:name=".InviteCodeActivity"
            android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden|screenSize"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait"
            android:permission="com.my.permission.INTERNAL_ACTIVITES"
            android:theme="@style/Theme.NoTitle"
            android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize">
      </activity>
      <activity
            android:name=".IPhoneProvisioningActivity"
            android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden|screenSize"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait"
            android:permission="com.my.permission.INTERNAL_ACTIVITES"
            android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize">
      </activity>
      <activity
            android:name=".ImproveLocationActivity"
            android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden|screenSize"
            android:launchMode="singleTop"
            android:permission="com.my.permission.INTERNAL_ACTIVITES"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait">
      </activity>
      <activity
            android:name=".CorporateLiableActivity"
            android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden|screenSize"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait"
            android:permission="com.my.permission.INTERNAL_ACTIVITES"
            android:theme="@style/Theme.NoTitle">
      </activity>
      <activity
            android:name=".HistoryScreen"
            android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden"
            android:launchMode="singleTop"
            android:permission="com.my.permission.INTERNAL_ACTIVITES"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait"/>

      <activity
            android:name=".HistoryDetailScreen"
            android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden|screenSize"
            android:launchMode="singleTop"
            android:permission="com.my.permission.INTERNAL_ACTIVITES"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait">
      </activity>
      <activity
            android:name=".ScheduleScreen"
            android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden|screenSize"
            android:launchMode="singleTop"
            android:permission="com.my.permission.INTERNAL_ACTIVITES"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait">
      </activity>
      <activity
            android:name=".CreateScheduleScreen"
            android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden|screenSize"
            android:launchMode="singleTop"
            android:permission="com.my.permission.INTERNAL_ACTIVITES"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait">
      </activity>
      <activity
            android:name=".activities.ScheduleCheckNotificationSettingsActivity"
            android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden|screenSize"
            android:launchMode="singleTop"
            android:permission="com.my.permission.INTERNAL_ACTIVITES"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait">
      </activity>
      <activity
            android:name=".ForgotPasswordActivity"
            android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden|screenSize"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait"
            android:permission="com.my.permission.INTERNAL_ACTIVITES"
            android:theme="@style/Theme.NoTitle">
      </activity>
      <activity
            android:name=".SettingsActivity"
            android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden|screenSize"
            android:launchMode="singleTop"
            android:permission="com.my.permission.INTERNAL_ACTIVITES"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait">
      </activity>
      <activity
            android:name=".WebviewDialog"
            android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden|screenSize"
            android:permission="com.my.permission.INTERNAL_ACTIVITES"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait">
         <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW"/>

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT"/>

            <data android:scheme="termsofservice"/>
         </intent-filter>
      </activity>
      <activity
            android:name=".PlaceScreen"
            android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden|screenSize"
            android:launchMode="singleTop"
            android:permission="com.my.permission.INTERNAL_ACTIVITES"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait">
      </activity>
      <activity
            android:name=".PlaceDetailScreen"
            android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden|screenSize"
            android:launchMode="singleTop"
            android:permission="com.my.permission.INTERNAL_ACTIVITES"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait">
      </activity>
      <activity
            android:name=".CreatePlaceActivity"
            android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden|screenSize"
            android:launchMode="singleTop"
            android:permission="com.my.permission.INTERNAL_ACTIVITES"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait">
      </activity>
      <activity
            android:name=".ChangePasswordActivity"
            android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden|screenSize"
            android:launchMode="singleTop"
            android:permission="com.my.permission.INTERNAL_ACTIVITES"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait"
            android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize">
      </activity>
      <activity
            android:name=".MyFamilyActivity"
            android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden|screenSize"
            android:permission="com.my.permission.INTERNAL_ACTIVITES"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait">
      </activity>
      <activity
            android:name=".ManageFamilyMemberActivity"
            android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden|screenSize"
            android:permission="com.my.permission.INTERNAL_ACTIVITES"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait">
      </activity>
      <activity
            android:name=".AddFamilyMemberActivity"
            android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden|screenSize"
            android:permission="com.my.permission.INTERNAL_ACTIVITES"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait">
      </activity>
      <activity
            android:name=".AddFamilyMembersActivity"
            android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden|screenSize"
            android:permission="com.my.permission.INTERNAL_ACTIVITES"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait">
      </activity>
      <activity
            android:name=".CancelServiceActivity"
            android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden|screenSize"
            android:permission="com.my.permission.INTERNAL_ACTIVITES"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait">
      </activity>
      <activity
            android:name=".CancelServiceFeedbackActivity"
            android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden|screenSize"
            android:permission="com.my.permission.INTERNAL_ACTIVITES"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait">
      </activity>
      <activity
            android:name=".DebugActivity"
            android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden|screenSize"
            android:permission="com.my.permission.INTERNAL_ACTIVITES"
            android:launchMode="singleTop"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait">
      </activity>
      <activity
            android:name=".signup.ContractActivity"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait"
            android:permission="com.my.permission.INTERNAL_ACTIVITES"
            android:theme="@style/Theme.NoTitle"
            android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize">
      </activity>
      <activity
            android:name=".OnboardingProgressActivity"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait"
            android:permission="com.my.permission.INTERNAL_ACTIVITES"
            android:theme="@style/Theme.NoTitle"
            android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize">
      </activity>

      <activity android:name=".activities.PaywallActivity"
                android:permission="com.my.permission.INTERNAL_ACTIVITES"
                android:screenOrientation="portrait">
      </activity>



   </application>

</manifest>
```

I am running out of ideas for debugging. Please suggest how to debug this issue.

**Edit1:**
here is the log lines from the point where I press the home button:

```
10-22 10:54:27.352 6836-6923 E/Surface: getSlotFromBufferLocked: unknown buffer: 0x91dd4440
10-22 10:54:28.256 6836-7766 D/FA: Application backgrounded. Logging engagement
10-22 10:54:28.258 6836-7766 D/FA: Event not sent since app measurement is disabled
```

Notice that there is an error `unknown buffer: 0x91dd4440` I am not sure what is that error.

**Edit2**:
I tried to put the log statement in `onPause()` and `onDestroy()` method. I see `onPause()` log statements, but I don't see `onDestroy()` log statement. This is really strange because when I check the application stack I don't see my application. When I try to press back button to go to my application is not  there.

**Solution**
I am just putting Ahmed's solution here so reader doesn't have to scroll all the way to the bottom.
My main activity configuration has this flag enabled `android:excludeFromRecents="true"` which was causing to not show the application on the application stack when user navigate to the other application. Once I set this flag to `false` (`android:excludeFromRecents="false"`) it started working again.
Here is the description about this flag from Android documentation:

> Whether or not the task initiated by this activity should be excluded from the list of recently used applications, the overview screen. That is, when this activity is the root activity of a new task, this attribute determines whether the task should not appear in the list of recent apps. Set "true" if the task should be excluded from the list; set "false" if it should be included. The default value is "false".

Comment: Please explain, in programming terms, what "my app gets killed" means. Or, please explain exactly how you are determining that "my app gets killed".

Comment: Share your error message in logcat

Comment: @CommonsWare When I check the application stack the application is not there. But I can see other application which were launch earlier.

Comment: You probably have an error in your `onPause` or `onDestroy` method. Send us your error log.

Comment: Check your manifest for `android:noHistory` attributes and your Java code for `FLAG_ACTIVITY_NO_HISTORY` uses.

Comment: @CommonsWare Thanks for the suggestion. I have already checked these two and these are not there in the code.

Comment: Can you show me your manifest?

Comment: @AhmedI.Elsayed I have attached relevant section of the Manifest. If you need something more then please specific the sections. I will update the description section.

Comment: @zilk is there way to know who called onDestroy method?

Comment: may you edit & add all <activity> tags please ?

Comment: @AhmedI.Elsayed I just updated the Manifest file please check it.

Comment: @Rakesh Sure, you can Override the onDestroy method of the Activity click the code line of the the method in Android Studio and run your application on debug mode. You can see who called the method like.

Comment: @Zilk Check the "Edit2" section. 
I still have to use the debug and check who called the onPause() method.

Comment: @zilk I try to put breakpoint in `onPause` and `onDestroy`. I am able to see that system is calling onPause but it doesn't provide more information. I also noticed that system is not calling the `onDestory` but application is closed without calling onDestroy of the activity. This is really strange.

Comment: @Rakesh your log lines doesn't give any information for us. There should be some Fatal exception etc. And also give us some information about your app. There is infinite possible reason to get this error. For example if your application play some music using MediaPlayer. and you don't close the  MediaPlayer, then you can the same error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, 
Make sure you don't have this

```
<activity.... android:label=""/>
```

for your Main activity.
You set it `android:label="@string/app_name"`
 , try setting it as `android:label="MyApp"`

### Also,

Make sure you have an activity with this

```
<action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
```

You can try setting this to

`android:excludeFromRecents="false"`

instead of true.

Comment: my application follow the same rules whatever you have specified above. But I still see the same result.

Comment: I can't find android:label in your manifest above even with ctrl + f

Comment: in my application label is not used for the Activity. It is used only for the application. Do you want me to put it for all activity?

Comment: It is working now. Thanks Ahmed. I didn't know that this flag is causing this problem. It makes sense after reading the description of this flag.

Comment: I'm glad to hear that, Mark as answered please

Comment: Btw, it wasn't killed as if you tried to open it, onResume(); will occur, that's why I suggested editing the title

Answer (score 0):

Share more info. Meanwhile, double check if your device is not set to killing your apps on leave `(Settings > Developer Settings > (Apps tab) > Don't keep activities)`.

Comment: I checked this setting before and it is definitely not enabled.